# React/Redux update state array if action id is not already present

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a set of actions to update Redux state. I'm struggling filtering the end results. Here are my actions

1. **GET_ITEMS** (GET request, returns a list)
2. **SET_ITEM** (POST request, `payload: 'id'`)
3. **DELETE_ITEM** (DELETE request, `payload: 'id'`)

Here are my examples:

```
case 'GET_ITEMS':
  return {
    ...state,
    list: action.payload, // [{ id: 'one', count: 1 }, { id: 'two', count: 2}]
  };
case 'SET_ITEM':
  return {
    ...state,
    list: [...state.list, { id: action.payload, count: state.list.length }],
  };
case 'DELETE_ITEM':
  return {
    ...state,
    list: state.list.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload),
  };
```

Only the GET_ITEMS action type returns a response data, the rest I have to manually update them. Bellow are my questions in the same order

1. How to update the state list array, compared to response data list array?
2. How to add an object item based on a id action payload?
3. Delete seems to be working fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper function for your SET_ITEM action:

```
case 'SET_ITEM':
  return {
    ...state,
    list: updateList(state.list, action)
  };

function updateList(list, action) {
    const found = list.find((element) => element.id === action.payload);
    if (found) {
      // ...update found props
      return list;
    }
    return [...list, { id: action.payload, count: list.length + 1 }];
}
```

I would definitely move the count property outside of the element because the way it's modeled we'll have unnecessary count property for every element and if we remove an element in the middle of the array, the count property will be wrong for every element on the right side. So a better state would be:

```
{
   ...state,
   list,
   listCount
}
```

Comment: Thank @Michael S. Molina for your input. That solves the 2nd point. What about the first point. Comparing the 2 arrays on the `GET` request: response array, with redux array. Update the Redux array with the one from response?

Comment: @ValeriCrudu I'm a little confused. When you do a SET_ITEM or DELETE_ITEM you don't update the data on the server side? Because if you did, GET_ITEMS would already be with latest data.